# Concatenate data if null

Tags: sql, t-sql

I would like ROW_Number() to work normally UNLESS column 'box' is Null.  If 'box' is null the row number doesn't increase.

I have data that looks like this...

```
Row Box
1   5
2   3
3   1
4   Null
5   Null
6   2
7   8
8   Null
9   Null
```

I want my query to pull out data that looks like this...

```
Row Box
1   5
2   3
3   1
3   Null
3   Null
4   2
5   8
5   Null
5   Null
```

I'm trying to avoid using a cursor but I can't figure out how to get this working without one.

Comment: Is Row an actual column name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a correlated subquery.  Here is one way:

```
select (select count(box) from t t2 where t2.row <= t.row) as row,
       box
from t
order by row;
```

This is counting the number of valid `box` values up to a given row.

In SQL Server 2012, you can do this with a cumulative `count()`:

```
select count(box) over (order by row) as row, box
from t
order by row;
```

These assume that `row` is set as in the question.  If `row` does not start with those values, then you have a problem.  SQL tables are inherently unordered, and you need some column to specify the ordering.